# How can I make a graphql query after another query is finish and use its data as variable?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

For example, I have a query component as below.

```
<Query query={GET_ALL_TYPES}>
    // some code here
</QUERY>
```

And in another component I also have a query component but I want to use the data which from the GET_ALL_TYPES query as a variable.

```
<QUERY query={GET_LIST} variable={data}>
    // some code here.
</QUERY>
```

How can I do this? wait a query data come back and make another query in different component?

By the way, i am using Apollo client version 2.1

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide exactly the GraphQL queries you are trying to make? And what would be the expected output?'

Answer (score 1):

You can access earlier readed data from cache: 
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/caching.html#direct